# How to return multiple resultset from a stored procedure using cte?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am just giving simple example of stored procedure which uses CTE.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE abc(
@startDate date,
@endDate date
)
AS
BEGIN
WITH allOrders AS(  
    SELECT  * FROM Orders
)
SELECT  * FROM allOrders;
SELECT  * FROM allOrders;
SELECT  * FROM allOrders;

END
```

When I am executing this stored procedure, It is throwing an error.
`Invalid object name 'allOrders'.`

How I can do this? I need to return multiple result sets using that cte.

Comment: you can use it like this : WITH UserPRecursive AS( select statement.. ) 
    ,UserCRecursive AS ( select statement...)
 SELECT userId FROM UserPRecursive AS CR1 UNION ALL SELECT userId FROM UserCRecursive AS CR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other two ops has already explain how CTE works I am not going to go over it again what you can do is to insert the records returned from cte into temp table and select from it multiple times,

something like .....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE abc(
@startDate date,
@endDate date
)
AS
BEGIN
;WITH allOrders AS(  
    SELECT  * FROM Orders
)
SELECT  * INTO #temp FROM allOrders;

SELECT  * FROM #temp;
SELECT  * FROM #temp;

END
```

Comment: Actually we are on SQL server 2000 , where temporary table is very slow, so is there any other way exist?

Comment: In sql server 2000 you dont even have CTEs, they were introduced in 2005. In Sql server 2000 consider creating indexes on Temp tables. Temp tables are always slow as sql server has to write and read data from TempDB everytime you make use of Temp tables. Creating indexes can speed up the read operations.

Comment: Is it good to use temp table(with index) or write two stored procedures differently using the same CTE but different select statements?

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is basically a for a single statement only.

*A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement*

Read more about [Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Consider using [Temporary Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) here, so you can use it more than once.

Comment: Actually we are on SQL server 2000 , where temporary table is very slow, so is there any other way exist?

Comment: @user3427540: Sorry, you will need to use Temporary table to achieve this